# How to display a text in fullscreen using RenderTarget?

Tags: c#, directx-11, sharpdx

*This is my first app, so I am sorry for a bit chaotic description.*

I would like to show "hello world" in fullscreen -- I downloaded SharpDX samples, there is "hello world" sample there. I changed the creation of the render form to:

```
_form = new RenderForm("hello world")
{
  WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized,
  IsFullscreen = true,
  FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
};
```

and then used `_form.Width`/`_form.Height` as size values for setting properties of `WindowRenderTarget` and rectangle size when drawing text.

**It works**, the sizes are correct, the text is not blurred (meaning it is not stretched, which would be effect of using different sizes).

This approach uses `WindowRenderTarget` and I noticed there is also class (`Direct2D1DemoApp`) using  `RenderTarget` in SharpDX samples so I switch "hello world" to use it.

I did the same changes and also I set `SwapChainDescription.IsWindowed` to `false`. This time however it does not work as well -- I got full screen but in such way that it looks I have some virtual workspace ~4 times bigger than the monitor resolution, and the monitor is just peeking at the top-left corner of that workspace. I can see only portion of the text, and it is stretched.

So there is somewhere scaling turned on, or there is some size different than what I set. But I don't see any place with such deviation.

So my question is -- when using `RenderTarget` what else is needed to get full screen? Original codes of SharpDX:

- base class -- https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Common/DemoApp.cs (this is same for both approaches)
- layer with swapchain -- https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Common/Direct3D11DemoApp.cs
- and class using `RenderTarget` -- https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Desktop/Common/Direct2D1DemoApp.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single line of the difference, since swap chain is created after form and I am relying on the form at that point, showing the form in the first place is required. So with this addition:

```
_form = new RenderForm("hello world")
{
  WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized,
  IsFullscreen = true,
  FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None
};

_form.Show(); // new !
```

I finally got the desired effect.